# How to Update one field value of one list into another same field of another one list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two lists of same class type.

```
List<CUSTOM_STU_DETAIL> StuList = new List<CUSTOM_STU_DETAIL>();
List<CUSTOM_STU_DETAIL> StuListforRollNo = new List<CUSTOM_STU_DETAIL>();
```

so I'm getting one list from two tables.

```
StuList = (from a in db.Student_Re_Admission
                           join b in db.Student_Registration on a.Registration_Id equals b.Registration_Id

                           where a.Academic_Year_Id == AcademicId && a.Company_ID == CompanyId
                           && a.COMPANY_LOCATION_ID == CompanyLocationId
                           && a.Class_Id == ClassID && a.Section_Id == SectionID
                           && a.Promoted == false && b.Delete_Flag == false

                           select new CUSTOM_STU_DETAIL
                           {
                               Registration_Id = a.Registration_Id,
                               Admission_No = a.Admission_No,                               
                               STUDENT_NAME = a.Student_First_Name + " "+a.Student_Middle_Name + " " + a.Student_Last_Name,
                               Class_Id = ClassID,
                               Section_Id = SectionID,
                               Academic_Year_Id = AcademicId,
                               Company_Id = CompanyId,
                               Company_Location_Id = CompanyLocationId

                               //RollNo = c.Set_Roll_No,
                           }).OrderBy(a => a.Admission_No).ToList();
```

so now want to get some values from another table with same condition on the first list loop wise..

```
foreach (var obj in StuList)
                {
                    var rollNoRecord = db.Student_Roll_No_Assign.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Company_ID == obj.Company_Id && a.COMPANY_LOCATION_ID == obj.Company_Location_Id && a.Academic_Year_Id == obj.Academic_Year_Id && a.Class_Id == obj.Class_Id && a.Delete_Flag == false);

                    if (rollNoRecord != null)
                    {
                        data.RollNo = rollNoRecord.Set_Roll_No;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data.RollNo = string.Empty;
                    }

                    StuListforRollNo.Add(data);


            }
```

so now wants to insert 'SetRollNo' field list of data into first list 'SetRolNo' field.

I tries like below but not getting what I mean.

```
    1) var listfinal = StuList.Concat(StuListforRollNo);
    2) var listfinal = StuList.Union(StuListforRollNo);
    3) var listfinal = StuList.AddRange(StuListforRollNo);
```

All are merging the data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are not change value inside foreach loop

```
foreach (var obj in StuList)
{
     var rollNoRecord = db.Student_Roll_No_Assign.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Company_ID == obj.Company_Id && a.COMPANY_LOCATION_ID == obj.Company_Location_Id && a.Academic_Year_Id == obj.Academic_Year_Id && a.Class_Id == obj.Class_Id && a.Delete_Flag == false);

     if (rollNoRecord != null)
     {
           //data.RollNo = rollNoRecord.Set_Roll_No;
           obj.RollNo = rollNoRecord.Set_Roll_No;
     }
     else
     {
           //data.RollNo = string.Empty;
           obj.RollNo = string.Empty;
     }
     //StuListforRollNo.Add(data);
}
```

Comment: Oh thanq..I didn't get that logic.